# What's the measure of the angle $ACD$ im trapezoid below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: On a rectangular trapezoid $ABCD$ right at A and B. Mark a point $L$ on $AB$ such that: $CL=AL=AD$ and $AC=CD$, calculate the measure of angle $ACD$.(Answer:$30^o$)

My progresss:
Follow the figure with the distribution of angles that I saw

$\triangle ALC: \frac{sen180-2\theta}{AC}=\frac{sen \theta}{AL=AD}\\
\triangle BLC: \frac{sen90}{LC=AD}=\frac{1}{AD}=\frac{sen 2\theta}{BC}\\
\triangle ACD:  \frac{sen 90-\theta}{AC}=\frac{sen2\theta}{AD}
$

...?
[image]

Comment: In triangle $BCL$ hypothenuse $CL$ is double of leg $BC$, hence...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca   I screwed up on this one
thankful